# MVC validation only border highlight without text error message

Tags: css, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I would like to only highlight the border of the text box without any error message near it, I have tried the following, but it still adds a span tag, can I avoid adding a span tag? Thank you!

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

view

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new {
            ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl
        }, FormMethod.Post, new {
            @class = "navbar-form navbar-nav",
            id = "userForm"
        })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new {
                    @class = "text-danger"
                })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {
                    @class = "form-control input-sm",
                    @placeholder = "Email"
                })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new {
                    @class = "text-danger"
                }) @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {
                       @class = "form-control input-sm",
                       @placeholder = "Password"
                   })
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-sm btnMain"/>
        }
```

Before
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QuX1.png)

After
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDwTv.png)

Edit: Added view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have added my view, appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried using css - `.field-validation-error { display: none; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yeah, I have still getting the same result as in image 2 : /

Comment: Works fine for me. - `<style> .field-validation-error { display:none; } </style>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke this worked for me => .text-danger  {display:none;}. And making a adding a new class after text-danger to disable only certain validation fields form showing the error message.   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new                   {@class = "text-danger nav-text-danger"}) and the css:                     .text-danger .nav-text-danger { display: none; }                                          .input-validation-error { border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important; }                   .nav-text-danger {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000 !important;
}

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you!

Comment: You should add your own answer and accept it to close this out.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have just did that. I can accept my own answer only in 2 days, none the less! Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have worked for me is adding another class to ValidationMessageFor in order to disable the text message only in certain locations.

New view:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new {
        ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl
    }, FormMethod.Post, new {
        @class = "navbar-form navbar-nav",
        id = "userForm"
    })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new {
                @class = "text-danger nav-text-danger"
            })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {
                @class = "form-control input-sm",
                @placeholder = "Email"
            })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new {
                @class = "text-danger nav-text-danger"
            }) @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {
                   @class = "form-control input-sm",
                   @placeholder = "Password"
               })
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-sm btnMain"/>
    }
```

They newly added class:

```
.nav-text-danger { display: none; }
```

in order to add the red border I have added/modified the following CSS class:

```
.input-validation-error { border: 2px solid #ff0000 !important; }
```

Special thanks to [@stephen-muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/) for helping me with this one

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your Validation Summary with a class and add the style `display:none;` for that in CSS:
**in View:**

```
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger hidevalidation" })
```

**in CSS:**

```
.text-danger .hidevalidation{
    display:none;
}
```